# iOS app launch time is around 10 seconds

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, launch-time

My App is taking around 10 seconds to launch.
To be clear, 10 seconds is the time between when i press the app icon and splash screen appears.
I have tried to put timer on main and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions calls. but it seems that these are getting called after the 10 seconds only.

To add some more details here,
This is the update of the app. Previous version of the app was/is working fine on the same device (iOS 8.3 OS), But not the current app.
The main difference between the two updates (except few new features which come into effect after launch only) is the change in the coredata-model.
For which , I have added a new dataModel-filename_2.xcdatamodel file.

Any idea/suggestions on how can I fix this launch time issue?

Edit: Just to add, I am not facing this issue on the "iOS 9". But there is one "iOS 8" iPad on which I am seeing this issue to the extent that app takes long to even come up from background (not just fresh launch). But Can't generalize this, I have tested on 2 devices only.

Comment: do you load lots of data on app launch?

Comment: give me app name... i will  check from here...

Comment: @nitin, I have added some entries in the existing data tables only. Ideally, it should not affect much and performance should be same as previous version only. 
Just in case, If you are talking about amount of data entries at the runtime, This issue is there even if I uninstall the app and install it fresh.

Comment: @FahimParkar: Please don't mind but I don't want to share the App name right now.

Comment: Checkout [Optimizing App Startup Time](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/) from WWDC 2016

Comment: @darklord : email me app name at parkarfahim22@yahoo.co.in

Comment: Try using Instruments to profile the code, and find out exactly what's taking so much time.

Comment: @TomHarrington: I tried to use time-profiler. Any entry from my app gets logged only after the 8-10 seconds. Nothing is happening in this time interval, even device logs are blank for this interval.
Any suggestions, how to figure out what's happening in between app-icon press and app-launch?

Comment: One update that factory reset the device fixes the issue.
Can this mean that there was some data/preference, etc stored on the device for the App, which was causing issue? If so, I tried uninstalling the app and do the fresh install many a times, but issue was present. Can there be some app-data remained on the device even after the un-installation?